# gemのインストールエラーがわからない

Tags: ruby, rubygems

`gem install nmatrix-lapacke`をしたところ下記のようなエラーが出まして，正常にインストールされていない模様です．
対処法を調査してもわからないので，どなたかご教授お願い致します

以下，エラーログです．

```
$ gem install nmatrix-lapacke
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nmatrix-lapacke:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /gpfs/home/home1/t163202/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nmatrix-lapacke-0.2.4/ext/nmatrix_lapacke
/gpfs/home/home1/t163202/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20190226-36390-ps5zbi.rb extconf.rb
using C++ standard... c++11
g++ reports version... gcc
checking for rb_array_const_ptr() in ruby.h... yes
checking for -llapack... no
creating nmatrix_lapacke_config.h
creating Makefile

current directory: /gpfs/home/home1/t163202/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nmatrix-lapacke-0.2.4/ext/nmatrix_lapacke
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /gpfs/home/home1/t163202/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nmatrix-lapacke-0.2.4/ext/nmatrix_lapacke
make "DESTDIR="
compiling nmatrix_lapacke.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wimplicit-int' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-self-assign'
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-constant-logical-operand'
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-parentheses-equality'
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-tautological-compare'
compiling math_lapacke.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wimplicit-int' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-self-assign'
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-constant-logical-operand'
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-parentheses-equality'
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-tautological-compare'
compiling lapacke.cpp
cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wimplicit-int' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-self-assign'
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-constant-logical-operand'
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-parentheses-equality'
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-tautological-compare'
linking shared-object nmatrix_lapacke.so
/home/1/t163202/.linuxbrew/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [nmatrix_lapacke.so] エラー 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /gpfs/home/home1/t163202/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nmatrix-lapacke-0.2.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /gpfs/home/home1/t163202/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0-static/nmatrix-lapacke-0.2.4/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

依存するlapackというパッケージが存在しないためにエラーとなっています。
お使いのOSに該当のライブラリを導入して再度インストールしてみてください。

https://qiita.com/AnchorBlues/items/69c1744de818b5e045ab
https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/flinux/rensai/linuxtips/a115makeerror.html